# Yield and Recursion

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm trying to setup a recursive logic using Yield. Here is my scenario: I have a collection of NodeviewModel items, and each NodeviewModel item can have multiple children of type NodeViewModel item. The depth of the graph could be 'n'. Basically, I'm getting NodeviewModel item and converting into a different form.

Here is the code:

```
public class CompositeContentBuilder
    {
        private readonly IContentFactory _contentFactory;

        public CompositeContentBuilder(IContentFactory contentFactory)
        {
            _contentFactory = contentFactory;
        }

        public IEnumerable<IContentViewModel> BuildFrom(IEnumerable<INodeViewModel> nodes)
        {

            if (nodes.Count() == 1)
                yield return BuildFrom(nodes.First());

            foreach (var nodeViewModel in nodes)
            {
                yield return BuildFrom(nodeViewModel);
                foreach (var viewModel in nodeViewModel.Children)
                {
                    yield return BuildFrom(viewModel);
                }

                //How do I return children.children...and so on?
            }
        }

        private IContentViewModel BuildFrom(INodeViewModel node)
        {
            var content = _contentFactory.Create(node);
            content.Initialise();
            return content;
        }
    }
```

How will I convert children.children and so on? Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

```
public IEnumerable<IContentViewModel> BuildFrom(IEnumerable<NodeViewModel> nodes)
{
    foreach (var nodeViewModel in nodes)
    {
        yield return BuildFrom(nodeViewModel);
        foreach(var child in BuildFrom(nodeViewModel.Children)) // recursive call
           yield return child; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The first yield won't compile as `BuildForm` cannot accept a `NodeViewModel`, it needs an ienumerable of `NodeViewModel`.  The second won't compile because you can't yield an `IEnumerable<NodeViewModel>`, you must yield a `NodeViewModel`

Comment: @Servy read all question first. There are two methods with name `BuildFrom`

Comment: Then only the second yield won't compile, as there is no `yield foreach` in C#.  The first will compile.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Your second yield still won't compile, you need to call `BuildFrom` on the child before returning it.

Comment: @Servy nope, I should not. BuildFrom will be called on each child during recursive call

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Not recursively, the non-recursive `BuildFrom` for a single node, because the return type is not of the same type as the input sequence.  It's for the same reason that you call it on the first `yield`, and why it compiles.  This is why it helps trying to actually compile your answers.

Comment: @Servy I really don't understand what you are talking about. Each child is converted to `IContentViewModel` during recursive call. Just before iterating over children of child. You can't see that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Stack` to mimic recursive behavior without actually using recursion.

```
public IEnumerable<IContentViewModel> BuildFrom(IEnumerable<NodeViewModel> nodes)
{
    Stack<NodeViewModel> stack = new Stack<NodeViewModel>(nodes);

    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var next = stack.Pop();
        yield return BuildFrom(next);
        foreach (var child in next.Children)
        {
            stack.Push(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Also note I'd suggest renaming the `BuildFrom` method that accepts a single node, as it creates confusion making the method appear recursive when it is not.

Comment: Does this version has any performance advantages or any other advantages compared to a recursive version?

Comment: @Mike Yes.  It consumes a constant amount of stack space rather than consuming a significant amount of stack space based on the depth of the tree, and avoid creating lots of instances of the state machine that iterator blocks generate, instead creating only one.  For small data sets it's unlikely an issue, but for large ones it very much can be.

Comment: @Servy as you have pointed once, this is not an answer, because question is about implementing recursion :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Sorry, but no.  He doesn't ask for a recursive solution.  He says that he's currently using a recursive solution and it's not working.  What he *asked* was how to return the children of children, and their children, and so on.  This does that.  But nice try.

Comment: Sorry, but no. Question title states it about recursion.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Yes, the topic is about recursion, but the question does not specifically ask for a recursive solution.  Recursion is a related topic since that is what his current implementation is using, and it's certainly what he expected the answers to use, but it's not something he *required* the answers to use.  I'll quote it for you since it seems you need the help: "How will I convert children.children and so on?" This answers that question.  It's fortunate that the OP had the sense to ask for what he really needed, and not how to do something he thought he might need (i.e. recursion).

Comment: @Servy: I think your implementation has a small issue, I was using this and the items were coming out of order or juggled.

Comment: @Mike You never specified that the items should be returned in a particular order.  If it's important that they be in a specific order then you'll need to specify what order they should be in in the question.  If you want breath first traversal rather than depth first traversal all you need to do is change the `Stack` to a `Queue` and you're done.  If you want some other order, again, you'll need to be specific about what it should be.